# Kmail mails missing

Tags: email-client, kde-4

I had a gmail account from which I exported all mails to Kmail before I deleted it.

The mails where splitted between a folder named **Local Folders** (about 10000 mails) and a folder named **gmail** (~7000 mails).

Yesterday I moved all mails in **Local Folders** to the one named **gmail** to be consistent, the changed didn't seemed to take effect (no meaningful message, apparently no action), however this morning I could see that mails where moved successully. But later on, after I tried and fail to archive all those mails (got "Failed to archive the folder %name% . Downloading a message in folder %name% failed.").

NOW I noticed that all mails previously in "Local Folders" are missing (about 10K mails see above), I can't find them anywhere. Any chance to get them back ? If so where to look ?

**Is Kmail a kind of bad joke ? Really.**